# Deserialize complex Json string with Text.Json and source generator

Tags: c#, system.text.json, sourcegenerators

I would like to use `Text.Json` and source generator to deserialize the following Json string but I can't figure out the correct syntax/view model to provide to my JsonSerializerContext class.

```
var json = @"[[{""OU2CJ3-UBRYG-KCPVS1"":{""cost"":""27187.08000"",""vol_exec"":""3.60000000"",""fee"":""27.18708"",""avg_price"":""7996.20000""}}],""openOrders"",{""sequence"": 59342}]";
```

I have tried with the following syntax withtout success:

```
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(OpenOrderFrame[]), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Metadata)]
public partial class OpenOrderContext : JsonSerializerContext
{ } 
 
public partial class OpenOrder
{
    public string Fee { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string Vol_exec { get; set; }
    public string Avg_price { get; set; }
}

public partial class OpenOrderFrame
{
    public List<(string, OpenOrder)> OpenOrder { get; set; }
    public string channelName { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}


var openOrders = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, OpenOrderContext.Default.OpenOrderFrameArray);
```

But the `Deserialize` method throw.
How correctly write the `typeof` argument of `JsonSerializable` attribute of my `OpenOrderContext` class ?

Comment: Can you change the JSON? In the sample, it is an array with different element types (first a sub-array of OpenOrder, then a string, then a sub-object with a Sequence property. It would be easier, if it was an array with a consistent element type, e.g. OrderFrame.

Comment: No I don't have the possibility to do that, I receive the Json string from a website and can't change it unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge with this JSON is that it contains an outer array with elements of different types:

- The first array element is an array itself that contains documents. The properties of the documents contain a key (the property name) and a value (the property value). This can be deserialized to a `List<Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>>`.
- The second array element is a string value that contains the channel name.
- The third array element is a document with a sequence property.

You can write a custom converter for this. If you only need it in one place and you have control over the deserialization, you can also use the following code to deserialize it:

```
// Get a Utf8JsonReader for the JSON 
// (this sample converts only the string, maybe there is a more efficient way in your environment to get a Utf8JsonReader instance)
var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
// Parse the outer array
var o = JsonElement.ParseValue(ref reader);
var frame = new OpenOrderFrame();
// First array element contains array of documents with string keys and OpenOrder values
frame.OpenOrder = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>>>(
    o[0], 
    new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
// Second array element contains the channel name
frame.channelName = o[1].GetString();
// Third array element contains a document with a sequence property
frame.Sequence = o[2].GetProperty("sequence").GetInt32();
```

Please note that I have adjusted your classes like this (especially the `OpenOrder` property of   `OpenOrderFrame`):

```
public partial class OpenOrder
{
    public string Fee { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string Vol_exec { get; set; }
    public string Avg_price { get; set; }
}

public partial class OpenOrderFrame
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>> OpenOrder { get; set; }
    public string channelName { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

In order to use a source generator, you can create a context that generates the mapping information for `List<Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>>`; *in the above approach*, this is the only place that performs a JSON to object mapping that benefits from a source generator.

```
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(List<Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>>), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Metadata)]
public partial class OpenOrderContext : JsonSerializerContext
{ }
```

You can use the source generator like this:

```
// First array element contains array of documents with string keys and OpenOrder values
frame.OpenOrder = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>>>(
    o[0], 
    OpenOrderContext.Default.ListDictionaryStringOpenOrder);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to use source genetator for low allocation memory impact

Comment: Your're welcome. I've added a section on using a source generator in the relevant part of the deserialization in this approach.

Comment: We have to deserialize the outer array first ? And so use undesired reflection etc

Comment: We can also parse the outer array. I'd hope that deserialization to System.Text.Json-objects does not use reflection, but to be sure, I've updated the sample to use `JsonElement.Parse` instead of the deserialization. So no reflection on the outer array anymore; also the second and third array element can be handled without reflection. Only the first elements contains a complex structure that needs to be deserialized. This uses a source generator, so no reflection here also. I'm confident that we took out all parts that might rely on reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for doing this :

```
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>[]), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Metadata)]
public partial class OpenOrderContext : JsonSerializerContext
{ }

public partial class OpenOrder
{
    public string Fee { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string Vol_exec { get; set; }
    public string Avg_price { get; set; }
}

[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(JsonElement[]), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Metadata)]
public partial class ObjectContext : JsonSerializerContext
{ }


var jsonElements = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, ObjectContext.Default.JsonElementArray);
var openOrder = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonElements[0], OpenOrderContext.Default.DictionaryStringOpenOrderArray);
```

But it leads to a little bit more memory allocation than @Markus solution. Should be nice if we could perform only one `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` call.